# Openlayers - Getting Incorrect LonLat while transform?

Tags: javascript, coordinates, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have trying to get `Latitude` and `Longitude` of a Point. 
But While transforming it's not returning the correct `LonLat`. It's big number that is not a `lonlat` point for sure.

I have tried for some solutions but didn't get result.
What else could be failing?

JS Code I have Tried

```
map = createMap("deviceMap");
var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 

map.events.register('click', map, function handleMapClick(e) {
          lonLat = self.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy).
          transform(map.getProjectionObject(), toProjection);
          prompt("",lonLat);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- EPSG:4326

  - should refer to WGS 84,
  - has decimal degree values
- EPSG:900913

  - refers to WGS84 Web Mercator
  - has metric values, it is x/y axis coordinate system, so "high numbers" are expected

If I understand you right, you should have in variable lonLat a high number.

"LonLat" in OpenLayers does not mean, it will be only longitude/latitude, see documentation [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/LonLat-js.html#OpenLayers.LonLat.OpenLayers.LonLat):

> - lon {Number} The x-axis coordinate in map units.  If your map is in a
>     geographic projection, this will be the Longitude.  Otherwise, it will
>     be the x coordinate of the map location in your map units.
> - lat {Number} The y-axis coordinate in map units.  If your map is in a
>     geographic projection, this will be the Latitude.  Otherwise, it will
>     be the y coordinate of the map location in your map units.

So if you want to get a real LonLat coordinates, you should not convert it (and use EPSG:4326) or convert it to the other coordinate system, not EPSG:900913.

By the way, OpenLayers started to use 900918 (numeric equivalent to GOOGlE), It was define by [Mr. Christopher Schmidt](http://crschmidt.net/blog/archives/243/google-projection-900913/), firstly it was not accepted by European Petroleum Survey Group (EPSG). Then EPSG changed their mind and gave them number: 3857 - WGS84 Pseudo-Mercator.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got answer

```
map.events.register('click', map, function handleMapClick(e) {
                var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
                var lonLat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy).
                             transform(map.getProjectionObject(), toProjection);
    });
```